# Insert values in variable while escaping URL "="

Tags: batch-file

We are receiving data in following format :

Variable=Value

I've an URL as a value, I would like to keep the delimiter "=", but keep the third and following "=" from the string.

Following code works, but only if there's only one equal caracter in the value.

FOR /F "delims== tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ("%temp%") do set %%i=%%j=%%k

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims== tokens=1*" %%i in ("%temp%") do set "%%i=%%j"
```

Does this work?
enclose the whole expression that is set with double quotes to avoid problems with special characters